# Simple Speed question - Mapping PWM values

Tags: power, pwm

I am working on an Arduino project for school to power a 12V DC cooling fan.

I want to adjust the speed of the fan. The instructions say to set the motor pin at an equation of `(0 to 9) * 10 + 150` to get a range of 150 to 240.

I need to write a mathematical equation but can not figure out what 150 to 240 means.  Is this voltage, resistance...?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The `analogWrite()` function takes a value that is between 0 (fully off) and 255 (fully on).

Your value of 150 to 240 is a value within that range of 0 to 255 and represents a percentage of the "on time" of the PWM signal.

- (150 / 255) * 100 = 58.8% on time
- (240 / 255) * 100 = 94.1% on time.

You seem to have an "input value" of between 0 and 9 inclusive.  Let's call this value "*i*".  You want an output value, let's call it "*o*".

The instructions say "0 to 9 times 10 plus 150 to get a range of 150 to 240". That is simple enough to convert to a formula.  0-9 is *i*, remember:

- *o = i × 10 + 150*

If *i* is 0 then *o* = *0 × 10 + 150* = *0 + 150* = *150*.

If *i* is 9 then *o* = *9 × 10 + 150* = *90 + 150* = *240*.

As Ignacio mentions, the Arduino API has a `map` function which is meant to be used for this kind of thing;

```
o = map(i, 0, 9, 150, 240);
```

*However:* the `map()` function is quite heavyweight since it is designed to be a generic mapping function for scaling values. Doi g the calculation manually will always be far more efficient since map will use steps and calculations that are not really part of your needed result. It's a bit like the differende between 1 + 2 and 1+ 5 - 3 + 2 - 4 + 2. The result is the same, but one is far simpler to calculate than the other.

Comment: Doesn't `map` just approximate with integer division instead of using floating-point?

Comment: Actually it looks like the current version does use long not float. I am sure an older iteratipn was float based. They probably changed it because it was too heavyweight. So yes, you can use map if you like, but since it is a generic function it will be less efficient anyway than doing the correct specific simple calculation.

Answer (score 3):

They're the value to pass to `analogWrite()` in order to generate a PWM waveform with an appropriate duty cycle.

But don't bother writing your own algorithm, just use [`map()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map).

Comment: He said he needs to write the equation

Answer (score 1):

The [map()](http://labs.arduino.org/map) function is the answer. It "rescales" the range of the data, using this formula:

```
(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
```

You input these five values:

```
map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)
```

- `value` is the X value you want to resize
- `fromLow` and `fromHigh` is the range that X is currently in
- `toLow` and `toHigh` is the range that you want to scale X to

Comment: The question wanted to know what the "150 to 240" means so, no, this isn't the answer.